# Added Spring Security, now I'm getting "No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring web application that is running just fine. I'm using JavaConfig, so there's not a lick of XML in the whole configuration. I'm trying to integrate Spring Security, but when I add a class that extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` as directed by [this tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html), I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:251)
...
```

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Did you declare a `ContextLoaderListener`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to ensure the security configuration is loaded. If the security configuration is not being loaded by other means, the AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer should pass in the Security configuration to the super class as [shown in the guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/helloworld.html#registering-spring-security-with-the-war):

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
      extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: that did the trick, but can you explain why that wasn't necessary in the tutorial I referenced (insecuremvc)? My application has a root config document in the base package that has @ ComponentScan, which is what I thought was supposed to pickup the SecurityConfig class... Great job on Spring Security to you and your team, BTW!

Comment: I figured out my problem... My `DispatcherServletInitializer` was returning `null` from the `getRootConfigClasses()` method, which is why it wasn't picking up the SecurityConfig class. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you figured it out :) and thanks for the feedback on Spring Security!

Comment: I have the same problem. My getRootConfigClasses() method don't return null, I had passed the Security configuration to the super class as said above but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same problem following the guide from the site.
Adding the code to the `MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java` solved the problem.

```
public MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
    super(SecurityConfig.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to add super(SecurityConfig.class) I get no default constructor found and I checked the class and there was a constructor with config parameter and no default, hence failed. Did anything change in 3.2.6?

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig.()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)